# Enrich Header at one FTP server and get the header at another FTP server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have successfully been able send file from one FTP Server(`source`) to another FTP server (`target`). I first send files from source to the local directory using the inbound adapter and then send files from the local directory to the target using the outbound adapter. So far this is working fine.

What I want to achieve is: to enrich the header of the message at the `source` with a *hash code* (which is generated using the file on `source` that is transferred) and then get that header at the `target` and match it with the *hash code* (which is generated using the file on the `target`)

Here is what I have tried so far:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private Hashing hashing;

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler sourceHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("Reply channel isssss:"+message.getHeaders().getReplyChannel());
                Object payload = message.getPayload();
                System.out.println("Payload: " + payload);
                File file = (File) payload;

                // enrich header with hash code before sending to target FTP
                Message<?> messageOut = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(message.getPayload())
                        .copyHeadersIfAbsent(message.getHeaders())
                        .setHeaderIfAbsent("hashCode", hashing.getHashCode(file)).build();

                // send to target FTP
                System.out.println("Trying to send " + file.getName() + " to target");
                MyGateway gateway = context.getBean(MyGateway.class);
                gateway.sendToFtp(messageOut);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

**FileTransferServiceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class FileTransferServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Autowired
    private Hashing hashing;

    public static final String FILE_POLLING_DURATION = "5000";

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> sourceFtpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(configurationService.getSourceHostName());
        sf.setPort(Integer.parseInt(configurationService.getSourcePort()));
        sf.setUsername(configurationService.getSourceUsername());
        sf.setPassword(configurationService.getSourcePassword());
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> targetFtpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(configurationService.getTargetHostName());
        sf.setPort(Integer.parseInt(configurationService.getTargetPort()));
        sf.setUsername(configurationService.getTargetUsername());
        sf.setPassword(configurationService.getTargetPassword());
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sf);
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "toFtpChannel")
        void sendToFtp(Message message);

    }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(sourceFtpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(configurationService.getSourceDirectory());
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter(
                configurationService.getFileMask()));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File> acceptOnceFileListFilter() {
        return new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>();
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel",
            poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = FILE_POLLING_DURATION))
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source
                = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(configurationService.getLocalDirectory()));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(acceptOnceFileListFilter());
        return source;
    }

    // makes sure transfer continues on connection reset
    @Bean
    public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        advice.setOnFailureExpression("@acceptOnceFileListFilter.remove(payload)");
        return advice;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFtpChannel")
    public void listenOutboundMessage() {
        // tried to subscribe to "toFtpChannel" but this was not triggered
        System.out.println("Message received");
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel", adviceChain = "expressionAdvice")
    public MessageHandler targetHandler() {
        FtpMessageHandler handler = new FtpMessageHandler(targetFtpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(
                configurationService.getTargetDirectory()));
        return handler;
    }

}
```

**Hashing.java**

```
public interface Hashing {
    public String getHashCode(File payload);
}
```

I have managed to enrich the message in `sourceHandler()`, built the message and sent it to the `target` but I cannot figure out how I can receive that message on the `target` so that I can get the header from the message?

Tell me if any more information is required. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two subscribers on `ftpChannel` - the target handler and your `sourceHandler`; they will get alternate messages unless ftpChannel is declared as a pubsub channel.

There should be no problems with your subscription to `toFtpChannel`.

Turn on DEBUG logging to see all the subscription activity when the application context starts.

**EDIT**

Remove the `@Bean` from the `@ServiceActivator` - such beans must be a `MessageHandler`.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFtpChannel")
public void listenOutboundMessage(Message message) {
    // tried to subscribe to "toFtpChannel" but this was not triggered
    System.out.println("Message received:" + message);
}
```

works fine for me...

```
Payload: /tmp/foo/baz.txt
Trying to send baz.txt to target
Message received:GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/foo/baz.txt, headers={hashCode=foo, id=410eb9a2-fe8b-ea8a-015a-d5896387cf00, timestamp=1509115006278}]
```

Again; you must have only one subscriber on `ftpChannel` unless you make it a pubsub.

Comment: Yes, in the logs it actually shows `Adding {message-handler:fileTransferServiceConfig.listenOutboundMessage.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'toFtpChannel' channel`. Placed a breakpoint in `listenOutboundMessage` but still it does not triggers.

Comment: I removed the `@Bean` from `listenOutboundMessage` but still the `ServiceActivator` was not triggered. Is it due to having 2 subscribers to `ftpChannel`? What changes did you make while running this code? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say what you are doing wrong; I copied your code and only changed the session factory configuration to point to my server, and it works fine for me; it has nothing to do with having 2 subscribers (although  that is wrong). Turn on debug logging and follow the message flow.